# Android Multipane ListView Search(List Filter)

Tags: android

I developed application with multipane .I need to give listview filtering.I have modified `@android:layout/list_content` file.But it didn't show `Edittext`.

My code is : activity_invoice_twopane.xml

```
   <LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

 <TableLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

     <TableRow
         android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
          <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/invRetName"
                 android:layout_width="240dp"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="ABCD Stores"
                 android:textColor="@color/black"
                 android:textSize="20dp"
                 android:textStyle="bold" />

           <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/invlasttxtDate"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="Last Invoice Date : "
                 android:textColor="@color/black"
                 android:textSize="20dp"
                 android:textStyle="bold" />

           <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/invlastInDate"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="2013-07-20 14:25:48"
                 android:textColor="@color/black"
                 android:textSize="20dp"
                 android:textStyle="bold" />

     </TableRow>

     <TableRow
         android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
     </TableRow>

     <TableRow
         android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
     </TableRow>

     <TableRow
         android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
     </TableRow>
 </TableLayout>

 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
     android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
     android:baselineAligned="false"
     android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:showDividers="middle"
     tools:context=".sale.InvocieBrandActivity" >

     <fragment
         android:id="@+id/item_list"
         android:name="com.xont.hemas.controller.sale.InvoiceBrandListFragment"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
         android:background="@drawable/list_item_selector"
         tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content" />

     <FrameLayout
         android:id="@+id/item_detail_container"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_weight="3" >
     </FrameLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

This is my edited list_content.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/progressContainer"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:gravity="center">

    <ProgressBar style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/loading"
            android:paddingTop="4dip"
            android:singleLine="true" />

</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/listContainer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <EditText android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Search Brands"
                />   

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" 
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />
    <TextView android:id="@+android:id/internalEmpty"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Please tell me what i want to do for show list filtering functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why do you need an EditText?

Comment: search , or list view filtering purpose

Comment: use textFilterEnabled http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html